# Sitecore PaaS using ARM templates throws "Master DB User Name is not recognized"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying Sitecore PaaS using [ARM templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates) within [Sitecore Azure Toolkit](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit/1x/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit_100.aspx) by running a **Powershell script that looks like**

```
$SubscriptionID = "[my Subscription ID]" # Azure Subscription ID
$Name = "myresourcegroup" # Resource Group
$LicenseXMLPath = ".\license.xml"
$ArmTemplatePath = ".\azureploy.json"
$ArmParametersPath = ".\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
$location = "East US"
Import-Module .\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev 170509\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1" -Verbose
Add-AzureRMAccount
Set-AzureRMContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -location $location -Name $Name -ArmTemplatePath $ArmTemplatePath  -ArmParametersPath $ArmParametersPath -LicenseXmlPath $LicenseXmlPath -SetKeyValue @{}
```

**The file azuredeploy.parameters.json has the following parameters**

```
{
  "deploymentId": {
    "value": "myresourcegroup"
  },
  "sitecore.admin.password": {
    "value": "AmVWnvU36KqD9xB"
  },
  "rep.authentication.apikey": {
    "value": "a2cce0b0-19cd-45a3-8947-f92d0ac4ecd2"
  },
  "analytics.mongodb.connectionstring": {
    "value": "mongodb://mdbu:mysecret@scmongo.mlab.com:13650/analytics"
  },
  "tracking.live.mongodb.connectionstring": {
    "value": "mongodb://mdbu:mysecret@scmongo.mlab.com:13650/tracking_live"
  },
  "tracking.history.mongodb.connectionstring": {
    "value": "mongodb://mdbu:mysecret@scmongo.mlab.com:13650/tracking_history"
  },
  "tracking.contact.mongodb.connectionstring": {
    "value": "mongodb://mdbu:mysecret@scmongo.mlab.com:13650/tracking_contact"
  },
  "sqlserver.login": {
    "value": "sql-admin"
  },
  "sqlserver.password": {
    "value": "2W4T7ZsAGcNHPkx"
  },
  "cm.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cm.scwdp.zip"
  },
  "cd.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cd.scwdp.zip"
  },
  "prc.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cd.scwdp.zip"
  },
  "rep.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_rep.scwdp.zip"
  },
  "licenseXml": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/license.xml"
  },
  "sitecoreSKU": {
    "value": "xP1"
  }
}
```

**And every time I'm getting the follow error**

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:26:16 AM - Resource
>   Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'sug-br4-prc/MSDeploy' failed with
>   message '{   "status": "failed",   "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>       "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "Failed",
>           "message": "AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared
>   parameter 'Master DB User Name' is not recognized.\r\n\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator
>   nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject
>   deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String
>   deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadAndDeployPackage>d__11.MoveNext()'"
>   }
>     ]
>    }
>   }'
>   At C:\Azure Provisioning\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev 
>   170509\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:26:16 AM - AppGallery Deploy
>   Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared
>   parameter 'Master DB User Name' is not recognized.    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator
>   nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject
>   deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile)
>   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String
>   deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadAndDeployPackage>d__11.MoveNext()'
>   At C:\Azure Provisioning\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:29:23 AM - Template output
>   evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed.
>   Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At C:\Azure
>   Provisioning\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:29:23 AM - Template output
>   evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed.
>   Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At C:\Azure
>   Provisioning\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: make below changes it will work
"sqlserver.login": { "value": "sqladmin" },

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, the error was expected as I used the same Sitecore package for different roles.

```
 "cd.msdeploy.packageurl": {
     "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cd.scwdp.zip"
},
```

and

```
"prc.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://mysitecorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xpscpackages/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cd.scwdp.zip"
},
```

As soon as I found it, and replaced by the correct package, the ARM templates were successfully provisioned.

**It should looks like this instead**

```
  "cd.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://stgscautodeploy.blob.core.windows.net/blob/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_cd.scwdp.zip"
  },
  "prc.msdeploy.packageurl": {
    "value": "https://stgscautodeploy.blob.core.windows.net/blob/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20161221_prc.scwdp.zip"
  },
```